# UICollectionView removes cells randomly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hi i'm working with a UICollectionView with pagination that request more data from api. first of all every thing is ok but when user try to scroll. Cells in collection view will disappear and each time i call `collectionView.reloadData()` `cellForItemAt` or `numberOfItemsInSection` wont call

I thought it is because an issue that remove collectionView `delegate` and `dataSource` but i checked again and the collectionView has  the delegate and data source and it wasn't removed.

I confiused a lot, what will happen to those cell...
I tried to check if cells are available in Debug View Heirachy but there is'nt any cell, that means the collectionView removed those cell.

[Video to where bug occurd.](https://mohamadreza.codes/share/bug.gif)

How is i implemented UICollectionViewCell for Test, it is storyboarded.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SomeCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! SomeCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
    return cell
}
```

And for pagination on willDisplay cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.item == self.medias.count-1 {
        if !self.isNetworkingCalled {
            self.isNetworkingCalled = true
            self.last += 10
            self.fetchMedia()
        }
    }
}

func fetchMedia() {
    guard let type = self.medias.first?.contentType else {return}
    self.indicator.start()
    Media.getCollection(type,count: self.countPerRequest, last: self.last) { (_medias) in
        self.indicator.stop()
        self.medias.append(contentsOf: _medias)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.isNetworkingCalled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify is `isNetworkingCalled` ever reset to false? Does the reload of collection view after fetching from the network happen on the main queue?

Comment: Are  you calling completion block of the API request on main thread?

Comment: @VadimPopov i use alamofire , i dont know which thread alamofire choosed...

Comment: @eeekari updated answer

Comment: Make sure you dispatch onto the main queue once you receive your response. Typically, one would set the ‘isNetworkingCalled’ flag to false too when the result of the API is received, and remove the ‘scrollViewDidScroll’ delegate method triggering change to that flag.

Comment: Share some verifiable example on git or somewhere else. This code doesn't help producing the issue.

Comment: @Kamran the problem occurred when the update calls in the main thread...